# Having trouble to exportmap in OpenLayer 3 + Javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to export the map, but I'm always getting the same error:

```
Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I have the following code:

```
var canvas = event.context.canvas;
var exportPNGElement = document.createElement('a');
exportPNGElement.download = 'Mapa.png';
exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(exportPNGElement);
exportPNGElement.click();
document.body.removeChild(exportPNGElement);
```

What is wrong? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you follow [the example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/export-map.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did it. But I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Javier, in future, please do not cross-post questions. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I am not answering your question. I did not check why your example does not work. But I propose using a different approach:

`canvas.toDataUrl` is very unreliable as the browser crashes depending on size of the exported file. It only works for very lightweight maps. For most real life applications you will have to use `canvas.toBlob` instead.

More info on canvas.toBlob: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

canvas.toBlob works in Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Browser_compatibility) and will soon be implemented in Chrome (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587#c101).

In the meantime you can use canvas-toBlob (https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js) and FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

See the examples here:

- Using native canvas.toBlob (works in Firefox):
  https://jsfiddle.net/oj7451L5/15/
- Using a shim for canvas.toBlob: http://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/raagKq

I have successfully downloaded 8MB png-files using this method.

I have opened an issue requesting to add an example using canvas.toBlob: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2968

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your canvas contains images that came from another domain.  You can get around the problem by supporting CORS (if it's your server) or using  a proxy.

See the following for more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image